# Laravel: Events and Mail not being logged to Telescope from feature test

Tags: laravel, telescope

I would like to see Mail that gets sent and is triggered by an Event inside Telescope.

I know my event is firing and the mail is sent because I have two tests making use of `Event::fake()` and `Mail::fake()`.

But on one of my tests, I'm not using the Mock, and I want to see the email that gets sent and the event that is triggered.

They're not being logged in Telescope.

The mail driver being used for tests on `phpunit.xml` is `<server name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>`

Is there a way to view the email that gets sent via a test?